# Layout for a Java program

Tags: java

I am making a program in java, which contains a jframe and has to be populated with some data. The data will be simply the various information(name of file,path of file, its size) of a file selected by user through JFileChooser. The JFilechooser will be open by clicking the jbutton which will be in the 1st column of each row and after selecting the file, data will be populated in subsequent columns for each row and the button will be added in 1st column of next row.

The problem i am facing is in choosing the right layout(container) for this data.I am considering following options,but have some doubts regarding it:

1. Gridbaglayout: not sure whether rows can be added at run time(on button click event) and managed effectively.
2. JTable: same as above.

Answer (score 2):

You never need to use a single layout manager. You can create multiple panels that each use a different layout manager and put them all together.

Generally adding multuple row of data you would use a vertical BoxLayout.

A JTable looks after painting itself as you add more rows.

Start by reading the [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are sections on using layout managers and on using JTable.

Answer (score 1):

As for layout managers take a look at MigLayout or at the DesignGridLayout. Both of them are much better than standard ones. If I were implemeting your program using standard layout managers I would use panels with FlowLayout and stack them vertically with BoxLayout.

Comment: I actually like gridbag layout. A lot of typing but a lot of freedom at the same time. Jgoodies formlayout is also very good.

Comment: hi,I tried miglayout and found out it to be very flexible but when i add elements in the panel(using miglayout) it does not add components in the required sequence.

Comment: hi,I tried miglayout and found it very flexible and easy but when i add elements in the panel(using miglayout) it does not add components in the required sequence. e.g if I add 4 components Label_1,Label_2,Label_3 & Label_4 (Label_1 being added at index 3 of panel)in a row and then iterate using panel.getComponentAt(index), getComponentAt(3) gives Label_1 but getComponentAt(4) gives Label_3. I can post code if it gives further clue about my problem

Comment: @sushobhit, unfortunately I do not use `MigLayout` myself. I use `DesignGridLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the group layout. It seems to be very flexible. However the code turns out to be a bit complex.

Comment: thnks for replies, i will explore the above suggestions

Comment: a bit complex is somewhat of an understatement.  This layout was built to be mainly used by software to create layouts, and not so much by humans.  I think you'll have an easier time with GridBagLayout (that certainly can be added at run time and managed then), and much easier time with MIgLayout or combination of layotus as suggested here as well.

Comment: I make all my forms in GroupLayout and I love how gorgeous they look. I code manually for this.  As long as you understand how it groups and indent well, it's easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You usually use multiple layout managers in more complex frames by putting related fields in a panel and give that panel its own layout manager.

Apart from that you can modify layouts during runtime. Afterwards I think you have to call validate() or something like that.

Also consider playing with a gui tool like the jformdesigner demo or google's windowbuilder pro ( free ). Even if you decide not to use generated code you can at least see what you' building.